# Firefox Extension Message: SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon

I have a problem with my firefox extension.
I would like check the current url with my webpage.

But I get this error:
**Message: SyntaxError: function statement requires a name**

Code:

```
loadjQuery: function(wnd){
  var loader = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"]
   .getService(Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader);
  loader.loadSubScript("chrome://clhelper/content/jquery/jquery-1.5.js",wnd);
  var jQuery = wnd.jQuery.noConflict(true);
  loader.loadSubScript("chrome://clhelper/content/jquery/jquery.hoverIntent.js", jQuery);
  return jQuery;
}

$(function() {
    $.get( "http://url/check.php?t=" + Document.URL, function( data ) {
        alert( "Load was performed. Result: " + data );
    });
});
```

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if you have (perhaps unintentionally) used a [JavaScript label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) on the first line:

```
loadjQuery: function(wnd){
```

I get exactly the same error in Firebug if I enter the line `test: function() {}` into the console.

Within an object literal, this would be valid, so

```
var a = { test: function() {} };
```

creates a variable named `a`, and the value of `a` is an object with a property with name `test`.  I could then call `a.test()`, which, of course, wouldn't do anything.  However, I don't think that your code is within an object literal. Outside of an object literal, a name followed by a colon is a label.

I suspect you meant to use either

```
loadjQuery = function(wnd){
```

or

```
function loadjQuery(wnd){
```

instead.